# <input type="text"> does not allow resizing

Tags: html, css, text, input, resize

I can't figure out why my input does not allow me to resize it.

`<input type="text">`

[Example of the problem](https://deepmotions.github.io/submission.html)

I only want to have a working resize on my biginput class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because `<input type="text">` is ment for a single line.

You'll need to use `<textarea></textarea>` for this.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="I can't be resized"></input>
<textarea>I can be resized</textarea>
```

In order to do this in Google Forms, use the option 'Paragraph Text' instead of 'Text' when selecting an answer.

Comment: It has to be linked up to my google form, is this possible with a textarea?

Comment: "When you define your question, select "Paragraph Text" instead of "Text".  This will give you a large box into which your users may enter several long sentences.  I have never tried to discover how many characters can be entered into a paragraph text box but it will certainly accept an answer as long as this one - and much more. "

via: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/D-DC8RudQJ4

Comment: Yes, I've done that and i figured out you can give a textarea a name="*" aswell. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need textarea for that :-

```html
<textarea name="entry.585452596" type="text" class="biginput"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is it possible to give the resize a maximum in width and height? *EDIT -
 Solved

Comment: DeepMotions You can add max-height and max-width properties to you textarea. You can also restrict resize in a single direction by using resize property as horizontal or vertical.